# Logic – Deduction in Tarski's World (Fitch/LPL 13.36)

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

I am working on proving the following question:

```
| ∀x [Dodec(x) → LeftOf(x, a)]
| ∀x [Tet(x) → RightOf(x, a)]
|–––
| ∀x [SameCol(x, a) → Cube(x)]
```

The question has the following rules:

> […] give a proof that uses Ana Con but only where the premises and conclusions of the citation are literals (including ⊥). You may use Taut Con but do not use FO Con in any of the proofs.

I have completed the following two proofs, but neither are accepted by the program, because it is being *very* picky on Ana Con:

Proof 1:
[image: Attempt 1]

Proof 2:
[image: Attempt 2]

However, I can't think of any other way to prove this that would make the program happy. What other methods could I try?

Comment: Ana Con refers to at most 1 other line. The first two, in both proofs, refer only to the corresponding row with [c]. The 3rd Ana Con, in the first proof, refers to nothing. The very last one, Cube(c), refers only to the line above it.

Comment: Use V Intro on the line `~Tet(c) ^ ~Dodec(c)` to make it `~Tet(c) ^ ~Dodec(c) V Cube(c)` then Ana Con will work I think. Fitch can be tricky though, if that doesn't work can you host your proof file? I still have fitch from years ago.

Comment: @hellyale I see someone created a tag for fitch! I was thinking a tag for LPL would be good.

Comment: The fitch tag already existed. I'd add a LPL tag but I haven't really seen a lot of LPL questions on here.

Comment: @hellyale Someone added the fitch tag after I requested it in a previous question. If you click on the tag, only my questions have that tag.

Comment: oh cool, well hopefully more people will use it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the rules you need to cite, ignore my comment, a disjunction introduction is not necessary. I was thinking it was of the form A V B not A ^ B. 
[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Fitch is very very picky. It rejected another question because I used [b] and the book wanted me to use [c], even though it really didn't matter. All the premises contained only variables.

Comment: @zagadka314 yes it also doesn't like b ^ a when it expects a ^ b. Curious, what steps did you have cited originally?

Comment: I cited the "~Tet(c) & ~Dodec(x)" line.